# Return a boolean function only when api call is complete in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a function which makes a call to Firebase Firestore db and returns the value of the same.
Here, the function returns the boolean value before the api fetching is complete. I guess the addOnCompleteListener is a sync function; so how do I make the checkProfileAvailable async.

```
private fun checkProfileAvailable(): Boolean {
    val userMail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.email!!
    var cgpa = ""
    var name = ""
    var end = ""
    var subjects = ""
    var board = ""
    db.collection("users")
            .document(userMail)
            .collection("dsfdsafs")
            .document("fgdsgfds")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    if (task.result?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, task.result!!.data.toString())
                        cgpa = task.result!!.data!!["cgpa"].toString()
                        name = task.result!!.data!!["schoolName"].toString()
                        end = task.result!!.data!!["endYear"].toString()
                        subjects = task.result!!.data!!["subjects"].toString()
                        board = task.result!!.data!!["board"].toString()
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG, it.message.toString())
            }
    return !(cgpa == "" || name == "" || end == "" || subjects == "" || board == "")
}
```

Comment: Yes, Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a custom callback or using Kotlin coroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback since you have to wait before sending a result back. Using your code

```kotlin
private fun checkProfileAvailable(callback:(Boolean)-> Unit) {
    val userMail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.email!!
    var cgpa = ""
    var name = ""
    var end = ""
    var subjects = ""
    var board = ""
    db.collection("users")
            .document(userMail)
            .collection("dsfdsafs")
            .document("fgdsgfds")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    if (task.result?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, task.result!!.data.toString())
                        cgpa = task.result!!.data!!["cgpa"].toString()
                        name = task.result!!.data!!["schoolName"].toString()
                        end = task.result!!.data!!["endYear"].toString()
                        subjects = task.result!!.data!!["subjects"].toString()
                        board = task.result!!.data!!["board"].toString()
                        //call the callback here
                        callback(//pass here the boolean condition you were returning)
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.exception)
                    //you should handle this case
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG, it.message.toString())
                //you should handle this case
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I implemented something like this with a separate callback interface and now works like a charm. This answer was really helpful.